# Sequelize-typescript create with per-existing association via through table

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to create a new role entry by using the sequelize create method via a through "table" called RolesPermissions and connecting it to a preexisting permission.
What it actually does is its trying to INSERT the permission(Although it already exists.)
I'm not sure if this is a configuration issue on my side.
NOTE: Each role can have many permissions and a permission can belong to many roles(ManyToMany)

Role class:

```
@Table
export default class Roles extends CreatedUpdateModel {
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Unique(true)
  @Column
  name: string;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  description: string;

  @BelongsToMany(() => Users, () => UsersRoles)
  users: Array<Users & { UsersRoles: UsersRoles }>;

  @BelongsToMany(() => Permissions, () => RolesPermissions)
  permissions: Array<Permissions & { RolesPermissions: RolesPermissions }>;
}
```

Permission class:

```
@Table({
  timestamps: false,
})
export default class Permissions extends Model {
  @AllowNull(false)
  @Column
  name: string;

  @Column
  remarks: string;

  @BelongsToMany(() => Roles, () => RolesPermissions)
  roles: Array<Roles & { RolesPermissions: RolesPermissions }>;
}
```

RolesPermission class (through table)

```
@Table({
  timestamps: false,
})
export default class RolesPermissions extends Model {
  @AllowNull(false)
  @ForeignKey(() => Roles)
  @Column
  roleId: number;

  @AllowNull(false)
  @ForeignKey(() => Permissions)
  @Column
  permissionId: number;
}
```